# Using generics with zustand's create method

Tags: typescript, zustand

I have a zustand store which holds `GridRow<T>` type items. This represents selected rows in a main grid, so it uses generics to represent the specific data used in the grid.

I'm not sure how to pass the generic to the store's `create` method. I can't wrap it an another function because it would create a new store each time.

```
interface MainGridState<T> {
  selectedRows: Array<GridRow<T>>
}

const initialState = {
  selectedRows: []
}

// T is undefined here, as I have no way to declare it
const useMainGridStore = create<MainGridState<T>>()(set => ({
  ...initialState,
}))

export const useMainGridSelectedRows = <T>(): Array<GridRow<T>> =>
  useMainGridStore<T>(state => state.selectedRows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
interface MainGridState<T> {
  selectedRows: Array<GridRow<T>>
}

export type UseDataReturn<T> = {
  data: MainGridState<T>;
};

const initialState: UseDataReturn<{}>["data"] = {
  selectedRows: []
};

export const useMainGridSelectedRows = create<UseDataReturn<{}>>((set) => ({
  data: initialState,
}));

export const useMainGridStore = useMainGridSelectedRows as {
  <T>(): UseDataReturn<T>;
  <T, U>(selector: (s: UseDataReturn<T>) => U): U;
};

// then use it
function Test() {

  // Use desired type instead of 'string'

  const dataExample = useMainGridStore<GridRow<string>[]>().data;

  const stateExample = useMainGridStore<string, GridRow<string>[]>(state => state.data.selectedRows)
}
```

Comment: There's no explanation here so I'm not sure if this is a good approach or not. But this isn't going to work because when I do something like `const store = useMainGridStore<string>(state => state.data.selectedRows)` it says it expected 0 arguments but got 1. Plus get lint errors about T and U being used before they're defined

Comment: I don't get any lint error and everything seems to work. Also, does this work for you? `const store = useMainGridStore<your_type, any>(state => state.data.selectedRows)`

Comment: P.S. updated answer with two usage examples.

Comment: Ok, using the two-param generic solves the issue. It's lame but because we export these the complexity is contained to one place. The undefined error is from eslint, so I think it's just not parsing the typescript object properly. I'm just ignoring them